# Rails Multiple Entries in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'll try and explain this as much and as easily as possible.

I have a Rails form, and 3 models.
Models: DemoModule, SalesDemo, and SalesDemoModule

What I want to do in my view/form is create a new SalesDemo, but a SalesDemo has many SalesDemoModules.

In the controller I have:

```
@sales_demo = SalesDemo.new
@demo_modules = DemoModule.find(:all, :conditions => ['active = true'])
```

How can I, in my view, have a text field row for each DemoModule, which I can pass back to the controller action, to save into SalesDemoModule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify that the SalesDemo `accepts_nested_attributes_for` SalesDemoModule, which then allows you to created a nested form (i.e. within a form_for a SalesDemo, you can have fields_for SalesDemoModule).  [Here's a simple example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#building-a-multi-model-form).

Comment: Thanks for the info, however this only seems to work if I have 1 SalesDemoModule? What I have is 10 DemoModules, and in the view, I want to list them with a text field. In the test field for each module you enter a letter, if the text field has a value in it, I want to create a new SalesDemoModule record, with the sales_demo_id and demo_module_id so I can link them up later on?

Comment: Check out this example for more details, including examples of 1 to many, including creating records:http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Simply put:

```
<%= form_for @sales_demo do |sales_demo_form| %>
  <%= sales_demo_form.text_field "some_sales_demo_property" %>
  <%= sales_demo_form.fields_for @demo_modules do |modules| %>
    <%= modules.text_field "some_module_text_field" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In the SalesDemo, you will need to have

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :demo_modules
```

You can get some more information [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for).